# Is there a global explicit natural logarithm formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, arithmetic

I heard that mathematicians such as Carl Friedrich Gauss, Carl Gustav Jacob Jacobi  and Srinivasa Ramanujana tried find such a formula, but were not able to. Is there a person who has done it?

EDIT: It would be a formula that links algebraic functions with elementary and higher transcendental functions - the fastest way to calculate the value for any logarithm + evaulate integrals containing lnx terms.

Comment: What do you mean?  $$\log(x)=\int_1^x \frac1t\,dt$$for all $x>0$.